# Codeignite 404 error

Tags: codeigniter

I ham writing the follow Codeigniter code, but I keep getting a 404 error. Any thoughts?

funding_controller.php

```
class Funding extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();

    }


    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('funding_model');

        $data['funds'] = $this->funding_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('funding_list', $data);
    }
}
```

funding_model.php

```
  class Funding extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAll() {

        $query = $this->db->get('funds');

        return $query->result();

    }


}
```

funding_list.php

```
foreach($funds as $row) {

   echo $row->opportunity_name;
   echo "<br />";

}
```

The default route points to funding_controller. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. controller name and class name should be same and file name in lower case

   > funding.php

   And try following url

   http://domain.com/funding/index
2. Model class name different from controller name like `funding_model` or anything else and no need to suffix `_model` in `->load->model()`

Comment: Thanks, I've done as you suggested but I'm now getting: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class funding in /webusers/ad6vcf/public_html/funding-list/application/models/funding.php

Comment: model file name and class different from controller for example `funding_model`

Comment: Please bear in mind that filenames and Classes of controllers must start with capital letter.Some (or all) server throws an error when calling controllers starting on lower case lettter. Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?highlight=controller

Answer (score 0):

Use first letter in capital for controller n model file name.

For example:

```
 Founding_controller.php
 Founding_model.php
```

And class name should be filename (as it is).